# Optimize an InterBase Query

Tags: sql, query-optimization, interbase

```
SELECT
  AI_636.PARENT_ID AS PART,
  MAX(b.AP_1036) AS ESTEND,
  MAX(a.AP_3222) AS ACTEND
FROM
  AI_636
  LEFT OUTER JOIN AI_665 a
    ON
    (
      a.AP_1033 = AI_636.PARENT_ID
      AND SUBSTR(a.AP_1028, 1, 4) >= '2000'
      AND a.AP_1030 NOT IN ('994')
      AND
      (
        a.AP_1033 NOT IN
        (
          SELECT AI_665.AP_1033 FROM AI_665 WHERE AI_665.AP_3222 IS NULL
        )
      )
    )
  JOIN AI_665 b
    ON
    (
      b.AP_1033 = AI_636.PARENT_ID
      AND SUBSTR(b.AP_1028, 1, 4) >= '2000'
    )
  GROUP BY AI_636.PARENT_ID
```

This query is a small part of a larger one and it causes the entire call to execute very slowly.

Basically, there is a parent operation and then several child operations underneath it.  The estimated vs actual end dates of the operations are only stored at the child level, so to derive one for the parent level, I am trying to find the largest dates at the child level.  The problem I run into is when a child operation is not completed, it has a NULL end date, and the MAX() function ignores these.  I am getting around this by joining the child operations table to itself and narrowing it down to only include child operations whose siblings all have non-NULL end dates.

Is there any way I can optimize the search for parent operations with children with non-NULL end dates?

Comment: Never worked with interbase, but the DISTINCT is likely irrelevant because of the `GROUP BY`

Comment: You're right, I updated my query a little bit and removed it.

Answer (score 0):

My last answer had a mistake, but maybe this will help:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                FROM   AI_665 a2
                WHERE  a2.AP_1033 = a.AP_1033
                AND    a2.AP_3222 IS NULL)
```

Comment: No, because that only checks if the current row is not null.  The extra sub-query checks all rows for a certain AP_1033

Comment: Aah, makes sense.  Did you try a NOT EXISTS?  I updated my comment.

Comment: That helped speed it up a little bit, but it is still much slower than I'd like in the grand scheme of things

Answer (score 0):

You must create an descending index to speed up the MAX()